# How to use upsert command in django for bulkupdate?

Tags: python, django, upsert, timescaledb

I need to update 1000's of rows each with differant values in timescale db.

I found bulk update to do so.

```
list = ModelClass.objects.filter(name = 'bar')
obj_to_be_update = []
for obj in list:
    obj.name = "Dear "+obj.name
    obj_to_be_update.append(obj)
ModelClass.objects.bulk_update(obj_to_be_update, ['name'], batch_size=1000)
```

This takes alot of time to update and even atomic transaction took alot time to update in the db.

Instead found upsert for timescale db which does execution faster. Any idea how to do it in django.

```
https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/write-data/upsert/#upsert-functionality
```

Comment: Do you only want to perpend some text to all of your records? for example adding "Dear" to all of your records? or is it a different text for each record?

Comment: Differant for each record @roham

Comment: Does this project help at all? https://github.com/schlunsen/django-timescaledb

Comment: The update is slow, does that help @greenweeds